Found the time consuming events in form displaying
I have two forms, formA and formB with formB inheriting from formA.
Displaying formB is kind of laggy so I tried to follow events fired by each form with some debug.print instructions.
Here what i had so far:
formA_Load Start        - 2024-10-03 14:54:43.549
formA_Load End          - 2024-10-03 14:54:43.557
formB_Load Start        - 2024-10-03 14:54:43.560
formB_Load End          - 2024-10-03 14:54:43.578
formA_Activated Start   - 2024-10-03 14:54:43.590
formA_Activated End     - 2024-10-03 14:54:43.593
formB_Activated Start   - 2024-10-03 14:54:43.596
formB_Activated End     - 2024-10-03 14:54:43.597
formA_Shown Start       - 2024-10-03 14:54:45.218
formA_Shown End         - 2024-10-03 14:54:45.220
formB_Shown Start       - 2024-10-03 14:54:45.222
formB_Shown End         - 2024-10-03 14:54:45.223

It seems that there is a time-consuming operation between formB_Activated End and FormA_Shown Start. What happens between this two events?

The UI is rendered. Too many Controls? Lots of Layout events? Background image stretched / zoomed?

FormB have 50 controls and 18 tablelayoutpanel. Is that too much ?
What do you call layout events ?

Finally I found that every controls use a background image with only plain color. Now, I use the backcolor property set to the correct color and the flickering are totally gone away.
